# Dynamic query with pivot on trigger not working

Tags: sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql, database-trigger

When data is entered into a table, I need a trigger to be executed to get the record, pivot it to the required format and insert into another table.

I have the trigger as follows

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[InsertTriggTest]
ON [dbo].[testtable]
AFTER INSERT
NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      DECLARE @var1 VARCHAR(100);

      INSERT INTO DBO.insertedtemp
      SELECT var1,
             var2,
             var3,
             var4,
             var5,
             var6
      FROM   table1 r
             JOIN table2 u
               ON r.var2 = u.var2
             JOIN inserted i
               ON u.id = i.id;

      SELECT @var1 = r.var3
      FROM   table1 r
             JOIN table2 u
               ON r.var2 = u.var2
             JOIN inserted i
               ON u.id = i.id;

      DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)

      SELECT @columns = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename(value)
                               FROM   insertedtemp
                               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).VALUE('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

      DECLARE @selectquery AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

      SELECT @selectquery = 'Select var1,' + @columns
                            + 'into temptable from ( Select i.var1,i.var2,i.var3 from InsertedTemp i ) P PIVOT ( MAX(var3) FOR var2 IN ('
                            + @columns + ') ) Pvt'

      EXECUTE(@selectquery);

      IF ( @var1 = 'test1' )
        BEGIN
            SELECT @sqlcmd = N'INSERT INTO test2(var1, ' + @columns
                             + ') select * from temptable';

            EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL
              @sqlcmd;
        END
  END;
```

However, the execution of the `@selectquery` (dynamic) doesn't work. When I change it to a static query it works fine. If I supply the values for the `@columns` variable (instead of dynamic creation of `@columns`) the query doesn't work.

I changed the `@selectquery` to a simple select query as `Select * from InsertedTemp`, but that too doesn't work (but changing it to a static query works).

I am having a hard time figuring out the issue here, as it looks good to me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the error message? Before `EXECUTE(@selectquery)` just `SELECT @selectquery` to check how the query got framed

Comment: Also keep in mind that, your trigger will fail when it is called parallel in different sessions because of this statement `into temppatientudf`

Comment: If you print the SQL statement before executing it, I would expect that you are missing a space between the last character of `@columns` and the first character of `into`.  You'll still have concurrency issues.  And it seems odd that you'd want to dynamically construct a `pivot` when `test2` has a static set of columns.  If a new `value` was added, your code would blow up because there wouldn't be a column in `temp2` for it yet.